# Can I use hooks inside a function (not a functional component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is where I would like to use my hook so that I can change one state during the run of the app.

```
export const simpleFunction = () => (state) => {
   // here is the hook 
}
```

I know react hooks should be used in functional components, but what about the case stated above.

Comment: No, you can't: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can! Those functions are then called custom hooks. But it is required to use those custom hooks inside of a functional component. So technically it is now a function using hooks outside of a react component, but they still need to be bound to a component later.

> Building your own Hooks lets you extract component logic into **reusable functions**.

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Example from the docs

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useFriendStatus(friendID) {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }

    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(friendID, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(friendID, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });

  return isOnline;
}
```

Because your descriptions is so short I don't know if this is what you are looking for. Hope I could help :)