# Can I use React Hooks outside a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a React App with latest React version. What I want to do is to call React useContext Hook in a function which is not a React Component. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use hooks inside a function (not a functional component)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69131540/can-i-use-hooks-inside-a-function-not-a-functional-component)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)

> ### Only Call Hooks from React Functions
>
> **Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.** Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
> ✅ Call Hooks from custom
> Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page).
>
> By following this rule, you ensure that all stateful logic in a component is clearly
> visible from its source code.

Comment: Please can you suggest any alternative for that?

Comment: @YahyaPatel What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider passing the context data into the function as a parameter, as you are not able to use the useContext hook outside a React Component.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned before you cannot use React Hooks outside of React, there's also not a ton of background information. What I could suggest is that you create a separate Context file importing createContext and useState from React. Then create a wrapper for further React Components

```
type ContextType = {
    someState: stateDetails | null,
    setSomeState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<stateDetails | null>>
}

type ContextProps = {
     children: React.ReactNode
}

export const Context = createContext<ContextType>({} as ContextType)

export const ContextWrapper = ({ children }: ContextProps) => {
    const [ someState, setSomeState ] = useState<stateDetails | null>(null)

return (
    <>
        <Context.Provider value={{ someState, setSomeState }}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    </>
)
```

}

Then you can wrap parts of your app with the wrapper but encasing the jsx in the new wrapper component so it gets transferred around the app.

```
    <ContextWrapper>
         <OtherComponent />
    </ContextWrapper>
```

This should be sufficient enough to create some simple context, for more advanced state handling look into [Zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/). Regardless, this context can only passed into React elements.