# Using hooks inside createGlobalStyle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

Hey I am trying to use hooks inside styled-components - createGlobalStyle.
I know that this is not possible, because createGlobalStyle is a function and neither a component nor a custom hook.
Maybe someone knows a workaround or a solution :).

```
export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
 p {
   padding: ${p => useMediaQuery('min-width(768px)') && 12px};
 }    
`
```

Comment: It will be easier to help if you share the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround can be to add a media query hook anywhere in your code, catch the screen size, send value in props (prop drilling, context Api, redux) to make your styled components adapt to your screen.

You may go through this [link](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props)

Comment: Yes that is one way how to solve it and it works fine.
But the I want to use p tag anywhere and it should be pre styled without me using any component if possible

Comment: One way I would try is changing props at the top of the react application tree, where my <App> component is.

Answer (score 0):

You are not need to use hooks outside of functional components. [Poof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69131643/13398368)

Two ways, which i see, how you can do your task.

1. add media query directly in `createGlobalStyle`.

   ```
   export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
   @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
     p {
       padding: 12px;
     }  
   }
   `
   ```
2. make `separate function` with some logic

   ```
   const minWidthMedia = (minWidth: string) => {
     const size = getScreenSize()
     const isValid = minWidth > size.width
     if (!isValid) return

     return css`
       p {
           padding: 12px;
         }
     `
     // or 
     // without validation logic
     // return css`
     // @media only screen and (min-width: ${minWidth}px) {
     //   p {
     //     padding: 12px;
     //   }
     // }
   }

   export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
     ${minWidthMedia('768px')}   
   `
   ```